# AngularJS toggle selected boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to check all boxes automatically when the user deselect them both.

To make it clear, there're two item in cards as it shown in the image, the cards are selected initially, when the user deselect first one, then the other card will be checked, then when the user deselect the second one, It should automatically select both of them again.

Here's what I have done so far:

HTML

```
<ion-list ng-show="transactionsCtrl.showCardBox">

<ion-item class="bg-blue p-0">

    <div class="dotted-1"></div>

    <div ng-repeat="singleCard in transactionsCtrl.cards">

        <div class="row p-tb0 m-t5" ng-click="transactionsCtrl.ToggleCardFilter(singleCard.g_id)">

            <div class="col col-20">
                <div ng-class="{'image-size-1-50 white-checked-image': singleCard.selected , 'image-size-1-50 white-unchecked-image': !singleCard.selected}"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-80">
                <div class="sub-title-white oslight">{{(singleCard.cardNumberMasked).slice(-5)}} <span class="m-l10 right {{transactionsCtrl.PlaceCardImageClassForFilter(singleCard.g_productSubCategory)}}">&nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
 self.ToggleCardBox = function() {
     closeAll();
     self.showCardBox = !self.showCardBox;
 };

 self.ToggleCardFilter = function(cardId) {
     // toggle on-screen indicator
     for (var c = 0; c < self.cards.length; c++)
         if (self.cards[c].g_id == cardId)
             self.cards[c].selected = !self.cards[c].selected;

     var idx = $scope.transactionFilter.cards.indexOf(cardId);
     if (idx == -1)
         $scope.transactionFilter.cards.push(cardId);
     else
         $scope.transactionFilter.cards.splice(idx, 1);

     self.applyFilterChange();
 };
```

Comment: i'm trying to implement the same logic like here 
https://jsfiddle.net/amrayoub/4a78xfpf/2/
into my code

Answer (score 1):

you can make it simple .
start with add current checked count variable

```
// and accept the full card not the card id  
 self.ToggleCardFilter = function(card) {
     // toggle on-screen indicator
     //for (var c = 0; c < self.cards.length; c++)
         //if (self.cards[c].g_id == cardId)
             //self.cards[c].selected = !self.cards[c].selected;
    if($scope.transactionFilter.cards.length){
       card.selected = !card.selected;
     }else{
       for(var i = 0 ; i < self.cards.length ; i++){
          self.cards[i].selected = true;
        }
      }

     var idx = $scope.transactionFilter.cards.indexOf(card.g_id);
     if (idx == -1)
         $scope.transactionFilter.cards.push(cardId.g_id);
     else
         $scope.transactionFilter.cards.splice(idx, 1);

     self.applyFilterChange();
 };
```

HTML

```
<ion-list ng-show="transactionsCtrl.showCardBox">

<ion-item class="bg-blue p-0">

    <div class="dotted-1"></div>

    <div ng-repeat="singleCard in transactionsCtrl.cards">

        <div class="row p-tb0 m-t5" ng-click="transactionsCtrl.ToggleCardFilter(singleCard)">

            <div class="col col-20">
                <div ng-class="{'image-size-1-50 white-checked-image': singleCard.selected , 'image-size-1-50 white-unchecked-image': !singleCard.selected}"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-80">
                <div class="sub-title-white oslight">{{(singleCard.cardNumberMasked).slice(-5)}} <span class="m-l10 right {{transactionsCtrl.PlaceCardImageClassForFilter(singleCard.g_productSubCategory)}}">&nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: the cards can be more than 2

Comment: ok can you give me example if the cards more than 2 what you need ?

Comment: I want to keep the code the same and add a logic like that one 
http://jsfiddle.net/amrayoub/4a78xfpf/2/

Comment: are you need the user at lest select one card ?

Comment: yes , but when the user try to deselect the last card , then it automtically select all cards

Comment: can you check the answer now again , i make my condition on the 
`$scope.transactionFilter.cards` as reference to selected card ID arrays

Comment: I test it on phone , it didn't work at all.
can we keep the original code and add a method in  'for' loop ?